# Is there a symbol for a number exactly greater than another

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, inequality, notation

Does anyone know if there is a symbol to represent “exactly greater than another number”.

I know that some people use ε (epsilon) to represent a number just greater than 0 in which case you could say that it is 1+ε for the number theoretically right after 1 or you could use 1-ε but that isn’t recognized everywhere and many times ε is just used as a variable ex: the delta-epsilon definition of a limit.

I came up with a question to explain where it would be useful ex:
$f(0)=0$,     And $f^1(x)$ is >2. What is the smallest possible number $f(2)$ can be

Now the answer is the smallest number over 4 but I was wondering if there’s a way other than with words to explain that.
I now would like to also propose/ask if writing it like this makes sense $^+4$ for exactly over $4$

Could I use $^+x$ or $^-x$ Like how in a limit I would distinct if you are approaching it from directly to the right or left of it.

Comment: "the smallest number over 4 " But there **is** no such number.

Comment: I don't think that you can define a notion of successorship in the reals like you can in the naturals or integers. If you could, then the reals would be countably infinite instead of uncountably infinite. -- This Numberphile [video about monads](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BBp0bEczCNg) might interest you, but this isn't part of real analysis IIUC.

Comment: @joseville "If you could, then the reals would be countably infinite instead of uncountably infinite." There's no connection at all between cardinality and (non)existence of successors. $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable but has no successors, while $\omega_1$ is uncountable but every element has a successor.

Comment: Thanks. Oh true. The rationals don't have a notion of successorship, but they can be [enumerated](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fcommons.wikimedia.org%2Fwiki%2FFile%3ADiagonal_argument.svg&psig=AOvVaw1xrevaGRgGv6e-ZMCXVbCO&ust=1637634124961000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAsQjRxqFwoTCPi3xtX0qvQCFQAAAAAdAAAAABAD) as I'm sure you know. Successorship is one way to enumerate and I thought that if you can enumerate the elements of a set, then surely they'd have to be countable. I guess that's wrong and one counterexample is $\omega_1$.

Comment: I guess even if the members of a set can be enumerated, the set can still be uncountable? I'm not very familiar with $\omega_1$ past what I might remember from Numberphile.

Comment: "you could say that it is $1+\epsilon$ for the number theoretically right after $1$". This is incorrect. Yes, $\epsilon$ is really small, arbitrarily small. This is the point, when we use $\epsilon$ we can make it as small as we need to or want to, but we can always continue to make it smaller.

Answer (score 2):

In the theory of [posets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set) (a set $P$ with a partial order $\le$), people use the symbol $\lessdot$ for [*covering*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_relation): $x\lessdot y$ for $x,y\in P$ when $x<y$ and there are no elements $z\in P$ with $x<z<y$.

For instance, consider the poset with the following Hasse diagram:
[image]

$9\lessdot5$ but $11\not\lessdot 3$ since even though $11<3$, we also have $11<6<3$.

**Note:** In particular, the real numbers $\mathbb R$ make a poset, so it makes sense to think about whether $x\lessdot y$ for $x,y\in\mathbb R$. It turns out that this is not possible; if $x<y$ then there always exists a $z\in\mathbb R$ (such as $\frac{x+y}2$) such that $x<z<y$.

Comment: Can the reals be made into a poset?

Comment: @joseville The reals are indeed a poset (in fact a totally ordered set). But in some posets, such as the reals, there are **no** instances of covering at all.

Comment: The reals is a poset, it is just that $x\lessdot y$ is never true, since whenever $x<y$, there is always a $z\in\mathbb R$ (such as $(x+y)/2$) such that $x<z<y$.

Comment: @KentaS thanks, that makes sense. Just that on first reading your answer, it sounded like if a set is a poset, then you could define covering. I guess, the point is, yes, you can still define covering on the reals, but it will always be false.

Comment: @KentaS I would put your comment into the body of the question, because I think joseville will probably not be the only one who reads it that way.

Comment: It's there a difference between saying a) a poset has no covering and b) a poset has covering, but it's always false?

Answer (score 2):

To be clear, the $\epsilon$ that shows up in things like limit proofs doesn't represent a value "just after" 0. Instead, it represents *any* value greater than 0, no matter how large or small.

In fact, in the standard construction of real numbers, there *is* no value small enough to be directly next to 0 - it's an important property that there are no gaps, and as a result if you have a real number bigger than zero then you can always find another real number that sits between it and zero.

You *can* use notation like $a^+$ to mean "in some neighbourhood arbitrarily close to but strictly greater than $a$", but it's usually best to be careful about not saying that something is equal to it. Instead, you could either define an interval $(a, a + \epsilon)$ (where $\epsilon > 0$ is some arbitrary amount) or you can talk in terms of approaching the point in question, e.g. "as $x \rightarrow a^+$" meaning that $x$ approaches $a$ from above.

There are other structures where you can talk about the number "just after 0". The integers is one case - in Peano arithmetic there is a specific function called the successor function that returns the "next" number. The successor to 0 is 1 ($S0 = 1$), the successor to 1 is 2 ($S1 = 2$), and so on.

If you want a structure that contains the real numbers but has successors, then you wind up getting into things like infinitesimals, but the problem is that if you want to introduce them you start to lose other properties of the reals that you might be used to. For example, if you have a value $dx$ that is somehow "just after 0", then what is $\frac{dx}{2}$? It can't be between 0 and $dx$, so either (a) it equals 0, (b) it equals $dx$, (c) it equals something completely different, or (d) it doesn't have a value. And any of these is a problem, because you're going to find that making $2 \times \frac{dx}{2} = \frac{2 \times dx}{2}$ becomes a lot harder than you might expect.