# Relationhips between successorship, enumerable, and countable

Tags: set-theory

I read a [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4312701/is-there-a-symbol-for-a-number-exactly-greater-than-another#comment8986567_4312701) here on math.se that made me question some my understanding of **successorship**, **enumerable**, and **countable** as they apply to sets. The comment is:

> $\omega_1$ is uncountable but every element has a successor.

My reasoning is. If each element in a set has a successor, then the set is enumerable. If the set is enumerable, then it is countable. Where does that reasoning break down?

---

Thinking in depth, there might be a definition successorship that doesn't guarantee enumerability, such as what if for the reals, $\mathbb{R}$, we define the successor of $x$ to be $\lceil x\rceil$. Then each real number would have a "successor", but the set of reals would still be uncountable. Is something like that going on with $\omega_1$?

---

In this post I asked some questions implicitly, so I'll just make it explicit below:

- Does successorship imply enumerable?

  - If each element in a set has a successor, is the set enumerable?
- Does enumerable imply countable?

  - If the elements of a set can be enumerated (i.e. if it is possible to assign a unique natural number to each element of a set), is the set countable?

Comment: Your reasoning that "if each element in a set has a successor, then the set is enumerable" is invalid: the straightforward enumeration process ($x,s(x),s(s(x)),...$ from some starting element $x$) might never reach many of the elements. Consider the set $\Bbb R \times \Bbb N$ with $s(x,n)=(x,n+1)$.

Comment: @Karl thanks. That's an illuminating example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You write:

> "If each element in a set has a successor, then the set is enumerable."

That's false: the existence of a successor operation says **nothing** about cardinality (besides, of course, the fact that any linear order in which every element has a successor must be infinite).

Intuitively, the existence of successors is a **local** condition. Knowing that in a linear order $\mathcal{X}=(X,\triangleleft)$, for each $x\in X$ there is a unique $y\in X$ such that $x\triangleleft y$ and no $z$ has $x\triangleleft z\triangleleft x$ doesn't do anything to control the size of the whole linear order $\mathcal{X}$ itself. In fact there is a precise theorem behind this intuition: the [Lowenheim-Skolem theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%B6wenheim%E2%80%93Skolem_theorem). No "simple structural" (= first-order expressible) property can distinguish between countable and uncountable infinities.

- Pet peeve time! Lowenheim-Skolem is really **two distinct** theorems. The "upwards" part is just a corollary of [compactness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compactness_theorem), while the "downwards" part is a genuinely different result. Lumping them together as "the Lowenheim-Skolem theorem" is pedagogically suboptimal in my opinion: it suggests that the two parts should be true for the same reason, but they **really** aren't. *(FWIW in the context of the OP, both parts are relevant but the "upwards" part is a bit more relevant.)*

Now it is true that if $(X,\triangleleft)$ is a linear order with successors such that **every element of which can be reached from some single element by applying the successor operation finitely many times**, then $X$ must be countable. However, this is a vastly stricter condition than merely having successors exist at all.

---

Meanwhile, "enumerable" and "countable" are synonymous *(OK some texts do introduce a distinction between the two by having one allow finiteness and the other not, but this isn't relevant here)*, so there isn't much to say there.